# How to allows access to a folder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have an htaccess to prevent access to a folder.

Howerver, I would like to one subfolder is allowed to be accessed.

Here is my htaccess file. How can I modifiy it to

```
AuthName "Private Zone"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /vdir/www.web.net/var/www/vhosts/www.web.net/web/folder/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Here is the folder that I want to be not protected

```
 /vdir/www.web.net/var/www/vhosts/www.web.net/web/folder/go/upload/
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a .htaccess file under **../go/upload/** with the following content:

```
AuthType None
Require all granted
```